# What is the equivalent word of villainy for victim

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns

> Villainy is to villain as *XXX* is to victim?

Sorry I couldn't think of a better way of explaining this

Comment: [AHDEL](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/victimhood) and Collins give **victimhood**, but I'd say this is rarely used. But you could have found this by looking up 'victim'.

Comment: How 'bout *helplessness*?

Comment: "Victimhood" has gathered new life in the jargon of American sociology. This link to a [NY Times](http://www.nytimes.com/2015/12/27/opinio/sunday/the-real-victims-of-victimhood.html?_r=0) OpEd piece takes a long look down this rabbit-hole.

Comment: *victimhood*.   If I were to try to transpose, "that is an example of utmost villany" into a similar phrase with "victim," I'd use *victimhood.*

Answer (score 2):

I believe the word you are looking for is [victimisation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Victimisation).

The relationship between the words can also be observed in the title of a BookRags article called "Does Shakespeare present the character of 'Shylock' as Villainous or Victimised?" and various [other sources](https://www.google.nl/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=victimization+and+villainy) across the internet.

Comment: Seems like "victimization" is more about the process of _becoming_ a victim, whereas "villainy" describes an ongoing attribute.

Comment: That is an interesting take, though I feel it can be defined more broadly. In 'I was victimized', the past tense does not imply that I am no longer a victim. Mental or physical, the effect of victimization may be an ongoing thing. 'Villainy' seems more of a label ('He still indulges in villainy'), with the 'ongoing attribute' being better described as 'villainous' ('He is still his villainous old self').  I would also consider that from villainy comes the villain, as the victim comes from victimisation (OK, the villain bit might not be worded right, but I hope that I make sense there).

Comment: Fair enough. If one were to come to a fork in the road at which one had to choose one life or the other, though, I think it would more likely be between  _villainy_ and _victimhood_...

Comment: I Agree, and in retrospect, 'victimisation' does seem to describe more of a process than a state of being, as victimhood does. It would depend on the context and how the rest of an actual sentence would be phrased, I guess.

Comment: @Terah - I reckon you have it right.  A villain *commits* villainy (over and over again; an ongoing occupation). A victim *suffers* victimisation (over and over; an ongoing ordeal).

Comment: victims are the objects of victimization, but villains are not the objects of villainy.

Comment: Villains practice (perform acts of) villainy, therefore the word we want must be what victims practice or perform acts of.

Answer (score 0):

Victimisation is an active verb pertaining to making someone else *into* a victim, not the state of being a victim. I think victimhood is the most accurate way of saying what you're trying to say - I have been trying to find the right word for it for a while, it's pretty frustrating haha

Comment: Please explain your answer, preferably with some supporting statements and references. :)